# SQL - Error Code "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, union

I try to make a timetable for all appointments in March and April 2030 of the
course "xy". I have some problems with getting this started. My SQL-Code so far is

```
SELECT  abhaltung.persnr  , abhaltung.raum_id , abhaltung.tag , abhaltung.lvanr, LVA.name  
from abhaltung, lva 
WHERE ((abhaltung.tag BETWEEN TO_DATE  ('2030/03/01','yyyy/mm/dd')AND TO_DATE('2030/04/30','yyyy/mm/dd'))
AND lva.name like 'xy')
UNION
SELECT abhaltung.to_hour|| ' : '|| abhaltung.to_minute as "BIS" from abhaltung
UNION
SELECT abhaltung.from_hour|| ' : '|| abhaltung.from_minute as "VON" from abhaltung
```

I run into the Problem that I Recieve 
" 01789. 00000 -  "query block has an incorrect number of result columns""

I know it might be that the renaming ad too many columns but I am unable to fix this somehow

edited (renamed and  some further clarification)

my output should look like

from        to
10:15       11:00
09:30       10:00

however, the timestamps  minutes and hours are in separate tabs
they look something like that

from_hour   from_minute     to_hour     to_minute
10              15          11          00
09              30          10          00

this is why I want to merge them.

Comment: @Gordon it did, just hidden by bad formatting. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what you're trying to do is compute the `BIS` and `VON` times and include them to each row. In this case you don't need to use a UNION, you just need to add the calculations to your SELECT:

```
SELECT  a.persnr,
        a.raum_id,
        a.tag,
        a.lvanr,
        l.name,
        a.to_hour   || ' : '|| a.to_minute as BIS,
        a.from_hour || ' : '|| a.from_minute as VON
from abhaltung a,
     lva l
WHERE a.tag BETWEEN TO_DATE('2030/03/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
                AND TO_DATE('2030/04/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND
      l.name like 'xy')
```

I've also shown how to use table aliases (`a` and `l`) to help simplify the code.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it similar. 
The main problem was the UNION  thanks to "Vignesh Kumar A" for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You first SELECT clause returns multiple columns, while the subsequent two each return a single column.  The UNION operator requires that all result sets have the same number of columns.

(I suspect that you don't really want a UNION at all, although it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 
I am sorry the whole names are German I will edit that in a minute 

my output should look like 

from   to
10:15  11:00
09:30  10:00

however, the timestamps  minutes and hours are in separate tabs
they look something like that

from_hour from_minute  to_hour  to_minute
10    15   11   00
09    30   10   00

this is why I want to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

First `SELECT` has 5 columns and other `SELECT` has one column for `UNION`. UNION must have UNIque number of columns in `SELECT`.

```
SELECT  abhaltung.persnr  || abhaltung.raum_id || abhaltung.tag || abhaltung.lvanr || LVA.name  
FROM abhaltung, lva 
WHERE ((abhaltung.tag BETWEEN TO_DATE  ('2030/03/01','yyyy/mm/dd')AND TO_DATE('2030/04/30','yyyy/mm/dd'))
AND lva.name like 'xy')
UNION
SELECT abhaltung.bis_stunde|| ' : '|| abhaltung.bis_minute as "BIS" from abhaltung
UNION
SELECT abhaltung.von_stunde|| ' : '|| abhaltung.von_minute as "VON" from abhaltung
```

Comment: so do I have to add the other column to this one aswell ?

Comment: Yes, u must add equal columns